# image uploading error in laravel seems not to upload after several checks

Tags: laravel, pdo, laravel-8

While I have tried uploading images and icons into a database, it shows an error message that says the image must be a file type. I have tried so many image file types, and it seems not to upload. I need assistance with this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'name' => 'required',
            'maincategory_id' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
        ]
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->getMessageBag();
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $messages->first());
    }

    $dir        = 'themes/'.APP_THEME().'/uploads';
    if($request->image) {
        $fileName = rand(10,100).'_'.time() . "_" . $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = Utility::upload_file($request,'image',$fileName,$dir,[]);
    }
    if($request->icon_path) {
        $fileName = rand(10,100).'_'.time() . "_" . $request->icon_path->getClientOriginalName();
        $paths = Utility::upload_file($request,'icon_path',$fileName,$dir,[]);
    }
    $subcategory                    = new SubCategory();
    $subcategory->name              = $request->name;
    $subcategory->maincategory_id   = $request->maincategory_id;
    $subcategory->image_url         = $path['full_url'];
    $subcategory->image_path        = $path['url'];
    $subcategory->icon_path        = $paths['url'];
    $subcategory->status            = $request->status;
    $subcategory->theme_id          = APP_THEME();
    $subcategory->store_id          = getCurrentStore();
    $subcategory->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', __('Category successfully created.'));
}

public function show(SubCategory $subCategory)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: What are contents in your vue/blade file?